# select code in php to android

Tags: php, android, mysql

i cant get data from my database..
my database is lcoalhost/phpmyadmin
and i wanted to select a specific data from my table..

here is my php code (select.php):

```
include_once("connect.php");    
$sqlString = "select * from loans where sssnumber = $sssnumber";
$rs = mysql_query($sqlString);

if($rs){   
while($objRs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){   
    $output[] = $objRs;  
        }   
echo json_encode($output);   
}    
mysql_close();
```

here is my android code (home.java):

```
public class Home extends Activity {
Button btnn;
 TextView txt1,txt2,txt3;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
  new task().execute();

  btnn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btnn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, Lista.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
 }

class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
    InputStream is = null ;
    String result = "";
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data...");
       progressDialog.show();
       progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
 @Override
  public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
  task.this.cancel(true);
    }
 });
     }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      String url_select = "http://XXX.XXX.X.X/XXX/select.php";

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

             ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
     HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

     //read content
     is =  httpEntity.getContent();     

     } catch (Exception e) {

     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
     }
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = "";
     while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
     {
        sb.append(line+"\n");
     }
      is.close();
      result=sb.toString();    

       } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
       }

      return null;

     }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

  // ambil data dari Json database
  try {
   JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
   for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++)
   {
   JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
   txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
   txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
   txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3);

   Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

   //get an output on the screen
   String no = Jasonobject.getString("sssnumber");
   String name = Jasonobject.getString("firstname");
   String birthday = Jasonobject.getString("middlename");

      txt1.setText(no);
   txt2.setText(name);
      txt3.setText(birthday);

   }
   this.progressDialog.dismiss();

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
  }
}
}
}
```

my JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {


 static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser(){

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();




            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

help.

error log in android:

```
02-04 22:02:21.089: E/linker(6348): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
02-04 22:02:21.093: E/(6348): appName=com.example.s_s_s, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
02-04 22:02:21.093: E/(6348): 0
02-04 22:02:21.093: E/(6348): appName=com.example.s_s_s, acAppName=com.android.browser
02-04 22:02:21.093: E/(6348): 0
02-04 22:02:21.324: E/log_tag(6348): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: What kind of troubleshooting have you done? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You should be able to narrow it down to any one of the three blocks of code you posted.

Comment: im stuck at "fetching data" dialogbox from the start

Comment: i posted the log cat error

Answer (score 0):

Please check your statement

```
$sqlString = "select * from loans where sssnumber = $sssnumber";
```

1) From where you are getting the value of the variable `$sssnumber`.

2) if `$sssnumber` is a variable, then the statement written above is incorrect.

Correct statement will be

```
 $sqlString = "select * from loans where sssnumber = '".$sssnumber."';
```

Try this and check

Comment: $sqlString = "select * from loans where sssnumber = '".$sssnumber."'; << i tried this sir, but i think something is still missing to the code but i dont know how to work it up..kinda messed up sir

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error log, you are not receiving valid json data so that would mean that this problem is with the php.

I don't know if you posted your complete php script, but there are some problems with it:

- `$sssnumber` seems undefined. You probably need `$_POST['sssnumber']`;
- Your query is vulnarable to sql injection. You should sanitaze / escape your variables (or use a prepared statement...).
- You are using a deprecated mysql api. You should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

Any of the above could lead to a php warning that would invalidate your json.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
include_once("connect.php");    
$sqlString = "select * from loans";
$rs = mysql_query($sqlString);

if($rs){   
while($objRs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){   
$output[] = $objRs;  
    }   
echo json_encode($output);   
}    
mysql_close();  
?>
```

this php code is correct, it selects all the details but it only selects the latest inserted data..what i kinda want is to get the data specifically with the said ID Number
example table fields:
ID Number
Firstname
Middlename

EDIT:
my id table name is sssnum
2nd table is fname
3rd table is mname
if i get the id number of 123 , then , the only shown result is the firstname and middlename of the id number 123

Comment: can you tell the exact name of your column which saves IDs